Excel - TypeScript executes slow from button, fast from script editor
I'm running a fairly simple TS script in Excel "automation". The script runs perfectly fine from the script editor frame (it's done before my eyes can move to the affected rows), but when I try to execute it via a button on a worksheet, it takes considerably longer (anywhere between ~2.1-5.3 seconds, average ~3.5 seconds).
Is there a setting somewhere that I'm not finding? I looked in the Trust Center settings, but only saw settings related to VBA macros.
Any help is appreciated!
Thanks :)

My wild guess is that, when doing it via button, updates make it try to sync/refresh. In VBA, code performance definitely improves if you turn off screen updating, for example. Try playing with suspendApiCalculationUntilNextSync & suspendScreenUpdatingUntilNextSync (see https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/javascript/api/excel/excel.application)

I'm getting errors when I try to use the methods in the way the API reference instructs. Even copying the example code, I'm getting a sea of red. The version of Excel I'm using is 2308 (Office 365 Enterprise), which is newer than the newest version listed in the Excel JavaScript API Requirements Set. Could this be causing the issue? (I'm usually really good at Googlefu and figuring my own stuff out, but it seems like the documentation behind this outside of MS is terrible.)

I wish I knew! If you ever find out the answer before someone else supplies it here, please post an answer to your own question!

I have a feeling from how these scripts behave that while editing, the code is local, but when you save it, MS stores it in the 365 cloud. Then there's extra delay while fetching it to run.

Hi @JSmart523 - the documentation you linked earlier is for Office.js, which is not the same as the Office Scripts API. I don't believe Office Scripts lets you control screen updates, but you can control calculation like so: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/scripts/resources/samples/excel-calculation Apologies for the confusion!
As for button performance, I believe that when you run a script from a button, it needs to retrieve the script which adds some delay (whereas in the editor, you already have the script open).

See related issue https://stackoverflow.com/a/78677929/570118
